# How to check if the object passed into a method isn't a derived type?

Tags: java

I am implementing an equals method for my class. I want to check if the object passed in is a derived type of the current class so i can return saying they are not equal.

I currently have:

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object obj){
   if(!(obj instanceof Car)){
     return false;
   }
   Car car = (Car)obj;
   return car.Number == this.number && car.Age == this.age;
}
```

So i also have a `Taxi extends Car`

So if i compare equals I want it to return false in this instance:

```
  Car car = new Car();
  Taxi taxi = new Taxi();
  print(car.equals(taxi)); // should be false but is currently true
```

My current fix is to add this to my equals method in `Car`:

```
if(!(obj instanceof Car) || (obj instanceof Taxi)){
    return false;
}
```

But this is a pain if every time i add a new derived type from `Car` i have to add each one manually to this check. Is there some built in way to check if its exactly `Car` and not a derived type of `Car`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the object's runtime `Class` instance directly to `Car::class`.

```
if (!obj.getClass().equals(Car::class)){
  return false;
}
```

If the instance is of a subclass of `Car`, then `getClass` will return *that* class rather than `Car::class`, and the two will not compare equal.

Comment: Would this also return false if i did  `myCar.equals((Car)myTaxi);`

Comment: Yes, `getClass` returns the runtime class of the object, regardless of what type the compiler *thinks* it has.

Comment: Ah interesting, thanks ! Will tick when the timer lets me!

Comment: Ah just realised this is a syntax error in my version of Java (1.8)